# missing static content when deploying to azure compute emulator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

Created a new cloud service project with a web role based in an existing MVC3 project. When I try to execute the web role in the **azure compute emulator** web site works fine except for the ausence of any images o css styles rendering the pages style less. When i try to access any of these missing resources (a css or image file, for example) by a direct Url on the browser only get an "Internal server error".

I've checked the obj folder under the cloudService project and despite all views and dlls are present, the Content folder (where css and images should reside) is empty when I run the project in the compute emulator, BUT IT IS POPULATED when I perform a deploy against the cloud.

As a result of previous investigation on the forums I've checked and rechecked that these files have "BuildAction=Content", and that Static Content module is installed in my local IIS without positive results.

I'm using Azure Tools 1.7 and VS 2010

**UPDATE:**
when trying to start the web role in the emulator (pushing play button in VS2010) two warnings arise in the windows Application Event Log that seem to be related to the problem (both warnings have origin in **IIS Express**).

here are the warnings (first in the original spanish version, later a personal english translation)

"El directorio especificado para almacenar en caché el contenido comprimido C:\Users\dgarcia\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\c122a014-7804-49ec-b59f-c9f23c924050\temp\temp\RoleTemp\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\d42ecaeb-eabb-4dd2-89b8-aecd01f36ba3 no es válido. La compresión estática se está deshabilitando."

"The directory specified for caching compressed content [very long temp path] is invalid. Static compression is being disabled."

(2 seconds later fires the second warning)

"Error del módulo FailedRequestTracing al crear el directorio '\?\C:\Users\dgarcia\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\c122a014-7804-49ec-b59f-c9f23c924050\directory\DiagnosticStore\FailedReqLogFiles\Web\deployment17(8).CloudService.BRAINVT.Web_IN_0_Web\'. No se generarán registros hasta que se corrija esta situación. El problema se produjo al menos 1 veces en los últimos 5 minutos. El dato es el error."

"Error in module FailedRequestTracing creating directory [weird extra-long path]. No more logs will be generated until situation is corrected. Problem ocurred at least 1 times in the last 5 minutes. Data is the error (?)."

**UPDATE2:**
Assuming that httpCompression is the root problem, tried to change this setting's directory attribute to point to a path like c:\temp which has open permissions for Everyone (unfortunately this cannot be done in the project's web.config file and must be done in IIS Express via de **appcmd** commandline tool) only to find that Azure Compute Emulator generates its own applicationHost.config file for each WebRole overriding IIS express' global config and therefore overriding the setting i've changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved.  I’m not happy with the trial/error method for solving this kind of issues and I ‘d prefer to understand the root cause but here is the process that lead this to work:

1. Deleted and recreated the cloud service project in my solution (not sure if this has something to do)
2. Changed the development server for my MVC project (the one in which the web role is based) from IIS Express to Built in ‘Cassini’. This took back my static content in the emulator (hurra!)
3. After that, knowing that I NEED IIS Express capabilities to test all parts of my project, changed back to IIS Express and… OMG! Static content remains.

This worked on 2 different machines. As said I’d like best to find the root cause but at the moment everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If the files would be missing, you should get a **File Not Found** error, and not an **Internal Server Error**. And if you see the files in your package when you deploy to the cloud this means your VS settings should be OK.

I would suggest you take a look at the event logs (the Application log). You can do this by configuring diagnostics or by connecting through Remote Desktop. If something else is going on, you should see an ASP.NET warning in the event log describing the problem.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the rapid response. The problem occurs when deploying to the local emulator ¿Can I RDP to the local emulator simulated VM? (I'm sorry if the question is basic but I'm pretty new to azure)

Comment: RDP to the local emulator is not possible. Could you verify your local eventlog? (Start > Run > eventvwr.exe > Application)

Comment: ok, there's a couple of warnings that seem to have some relation with the problem. I'll update the question to add these warnings

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a local IIS setting issue - could you try out the suggestions at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735199(v=ws.10).aspx to change the compression settings and try again.

Comment: I can not apply the procedures described in the technet article because they refer to IIS management Console which is not available for IIS 7.5 Express... I know there's a cmd tool called appcmd that can manage IIS Express config but it is quite obscure for me and I'm now trying to figure out how it works. I'll keep this question updated...